# Mongoose pushing in an array in a nested subdocument

Tags: mongoose, updates

I have this schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    firstName: {type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    lastName: {type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    city: {type: String}
    age: {type: Number, min: 13, max: 120},
    image: {type: String,trim: true}
  },
  friends:{
    accepted:[{
       id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
       dateAccepted: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    }]
  }
}
```

How can I push data in friends.accepted with .update method ?

I succeed only with the findOne method:

```
User.findOne({
  _id: id
  },function(err,user){
    user.friends.accepted.push(newUser._id);
    user.save(function(err){if(err) return err;})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: id
}, {
  $push: {
    "friends.accepted": {
      id: newUser._id
    }
  }
},
{
  new: true
},
function (err, user) {
  console.log(err, user);
});
```

You can also use User.update, but the second parameter of the callback will be the result of the update query: `{ ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }`

Using [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) allows you to get the user object. Passing `new: true` in the options allows you to get the updated user object, whereas without it, you would get the original.

Comment: I found the answer, with update, it's 
    _id:newUser._id
even if in my model it's id